# Getting the next UL element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find the next ul element in a give webpage.

I start by plugging in my response into Beautiful Soup like so:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.context)
```

printing out response.context gives the following

```
print(response.context)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> | FollowUp</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <link href='/static/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='navbar'>
            <div class='navbar-inner'>
                <a class='brand' href='/'>TellMe.cat</a>
                <ul class='nav'>
                    <li><a href='list'>My Stories</a></li>
                    <li><a href='add'>Add Story</a></li>
                    <li><a href='respond'>Add Update</a></li>
                </ul>

                <form class='navbar-form pull-right' action='process_logout' method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='RxquwEsaS5Bn1MsKOIJP8uLtRZ9yDusH' />
                    Hello add!
                    <button class='btn btn-small'>Logout</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container'>

<ul id='items'>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.example.org'>http://www.example.org</a></li>
<ul>
<p>There have been no follow ups.</p>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>

        </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='/static/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get the ul that's named 'items'. I do so with:

```
items = soup.find(id='items')
```

Which gives me the correct ul and all of its children. However calling

```
items.find_next('ul')
```

Gives the error of

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Even though this seems to be how it's supposed to be called accorind to the Beautiful Soup docs: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#find-all-next-and-find-next

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: cant you do `find_all` which returns a list?

Comment: I cannot, as it gives the same error. Items is of type BeautifulSoup.Tag, not a NoneType

Comment: `dir()` is your friend. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir Or run this in ipython and use tab completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), `pip install BeautifulSoup requests`, open python console.

```
import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get("http://yahoo.com").text
b = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
m = b.find(id='masthead')
item = m.findNext('ul')
```

`dir(m)` tells you the functions on `m`. You can see you want `findNext`.

You also might find [ipython](http://ipython.org/) a more forgiving shell to run python in. You can type the name of a variable and hit Tab to see the member variables.